# Haskell || Missing Null Element

Tags: haskell, null

I need to create a function that takes the first element of a String but because I am using this function recursively in an other function I need to declare an Edge Case for an Empty List. How can this function do nothing if its given an empty list.

```
takeFirstElem :: String -> Char
takeFirstElem [] = {- missing Element -}
takeFirstElem (x:xs) = x
```

What I am missing is something similar to a null element (Like the nil element in an empty List [] ). Does something like this exist or is there an other way to solve this problem?

Comment: There is a NULL character, but you can not return "nothing". You are supposed to return always a `Char` per type signature. Often if the input can be invalid, a `Maybe Char` is returned and it thus returns a `Nothing` in case the input is invalid, and a `Just x` here in case the input is valid.

Comment: You should definitely return a `Maybe Char` rather than a `Char` to handle this. Thereby avoiding the famous "billion dollar mistake" of allowing "null" to be treated as a genuine value.

Comment: This function seems an odd one to use recursively. Why aren't you just pattern matching on the string in your larger function?

Comment: "How can this function do nothing if its given an empty list." Here is where you need to change your thinking to really **get** functional programming. It's not just that you can't make this function "do nothing"; the *idea* of "doing nothing" doesn't make any sense. This function is *called* from other places; those places are going to do something with the returned `Char`, so there has to ***be*** a return value. Sometimes when you can't implement the type it tells you that you've broken down your problem into the wrong parts, rather than that you can't find the code that works.

Comment: Some other languages give you a `null` value in every type, which allows you to always have the option of giving up and returning `null` whenever it's impossible to return a useful value. But that also means that you have to deal with every value of unknown provenance possibly not actually being there. And it would make this kind of function utterly useless because if the caller has to check for `null` they might as well have just checked for `[]` themselves and not bothered to call this function, so why even write it?

Comment: Haskell *does* have bottoms (like `undefined`) in every type, but avoids much of the temptation to build a "just return `undefined` whenever you don't have a real value" convention because it's impossible for the caller to check whether a called function bottomed out; the error propagates all the way out. There are functions that do this (we call them partial functions), including unfortunately things in the prelude like `head`, `fromJust`, etc. These days it's pretty much consensus that partial functions are a code smell you should try to avoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [NULL character `\NUL` [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), but you can not return "*nothing*". You are supposed to return always a `Char` per type signature.

Often if the input can be invalid, a `Maybe Char` is returned and it thus returns a `Nothing` in case the input is invalid, and a `Just x` here in case the input is valid, so you can implement this as:

```
takeFirstElem :: String -> Maybe Char
takeFirstElem [] = Nothing
takeFirstElem (x:_) = Just x
```

in that case, your `takeFirstElem` is a special case of [**`listToMaybe :: [a] -> Maybe a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:listToMaybe).